# Splash Screen (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to upload the splash image in its original quality instead of the white background color. How is it?

I tried to do that but the white background appears.

[image]

I injected the image before building:

[image]

The Splash Screen:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}
    class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(),)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/background_image.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black26, BlendMode.darken),
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.all(50),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              boxShadow: AppColors.boxShadow,
            ),
            child: const Text('Logo'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setting a launch image in Android**

Setting a launch image in Android Studio: navigate in the Project browser to android/app/src/main/res/drawable/ and open launch_background.xml.
Add the following code inside the layer-list node, after the first item:

```
<item>
  <bitmap
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_image" />
</item>
```

Copy splash_image.png to android/app/src/main/res/drawable.

**Setting a launch image in iOS**

In Xcode, open ios/Runner.xcworkspace, select Assets.xcassets, and select LaunchImage. You’ll see three boxes to represent the image at 1x, 2x and 3x resolution. Drag images onto the boxes. If you have one image, select from the Scales drop-down: Single Scale.
You can create even more sophisticated launch screen: adding constraints, label e.t.c.

Answer (score 2):

This white background appears because when main.dart file call at that time all channel method are build after then flutter repaint screens. So during that time  white screen appear. You can use [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) it will show splash screen during method channel build.

Comment: In this library, you cannot build the same shape that I want because it does not contain widgets to the widget other than the image and logo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the asset in init state function like `_image = AssetImage('assets/images/background_image.png');`. Remove the Scaffold backgroundColor parameter, then use decoration -> image: _image?

Maybe the asset takes this split second to load after the page is constructed. If it's a particularly big asset it could be the case. Try loading it before the page is shown.

Comment: I did that and it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'DashBoard.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(SplashScreen());
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();

}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 4),(){
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => DashBoard(),
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(child: Text('xyz', style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).